# How to find elements by substring of ID using selector-syntax Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, regex, jsoup

I have used Jsoup to fetch a page from a URL. I can extract the link of certain id using the following line of code:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]#title0");
```

How can I find the elements if I only know the part of its ID for example 'title'. I know that I could find all the **a** links with the **href** and then iterate through the 'links' and check whether it's id contains 'title' substring or not however I would like to avoid this approach. Is there a way to filter the links in the selector and check whether it's id contains 'title' substring?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[id^=nav]");
```

this would return all the links with id starting with string "nav"

The following will return all the links with id containing string "logo"

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[id~=logo]");
```

Answer (score 2):

@alex-ackerman 's answer is half correct, but the other half is wrong.

> [attr^=valPrefix] elements with an attribute named "attr", and value
>   starting with "valPrefix" [attr$=valSuffix]   elements with an attribute
>   named "attr", and value ending with "valSuffix"
>   [attr*=valContaining] elements with an attribute named "attr", and
>   value containing "valContaining" [attr~=regex]    elements with an
>   attribute named "attr", and value matching the regular expression The
>   above may be combined in any order

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html